# Determine PostgreSQL mode

Tags: postgresql, mode, wal

I have inherited a PostgreSQL 13 cluster which was setup using log shipping.  I had to make a few changes and would to confirm everything is working well.

1. Is there a command to make pgsql report whether it is in standby mode or active mode?
2. Is there a command to make pgsql report up to which WAL file it has applied changes?
3. I assume that the only way to test the wal shipping is working is to manually modify the active db server and watch for the change on the standby?

I know there are better ways to setup a cluster, but for now I just need to ensure the system remains operational as setup.

Comment: 1. [`select pg_is_in_recovery();`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-RECOVERY-CONTROL) 2. `select pg_walfile_name(pg_last_wal_replay_lsn());`

Comment: 3. Use `pg_wal_lsn_diff()` to get the difference between `pg_current_wal_lsn()` on the primary and `pg_last_wal_replay_lsn()` on the standby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-RECOVERY-CONTROL):

1. `select pg_is_in_recovery();`
2. `select pg_walfile_name(pg_last_wal_replay_lsn());`
3. Either that or `select pg_current_wal_lsn();` on the primary, then `select pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn__taken_from_primary,pg_last_wal_replay_lsn());` on standby as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74112236/determine-postgresql-mode#comment130852828_74112236) by [@Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe).

Comment: I think #1 just shows if db is in recovery - but does recovery end then it stays in standby mode?  On the node I think is in standby the psql command won't even run because "the database system is starting up"...which I think will stay that way while in standby?

Comment: I think `pg_is_in_recovery()` is typically recommended because a [standby doesn't exit the recovery mode, looping through recovery steps until promoted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-OPERATION). Another method would be to check for the presence of a `standby.signal` flag file under whatever directory is set as data directory (`show data_directory;`) but that requires reaching into the file system directly or being able to do so from the context of your user. I'll update my answer to show an example of that.

Comment: How would I run pg_is_in_recovery() if the the postgres service is looping in recovery mode?  The psql command just reports that the database is starting.  Is there another way to run that command from the command line?

Comment: If you have the access to the command line of the machine the standby db's engine is running on, you can just check if the `standby.signal` file is present. The data_directory setting is in the `postgresql.conf` file, `/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf` on Debian - replace 15 with your version number.